# Difference between compliment, louange and éloge

Tags: synonymes

Is there any difference between "compliment", "louange" and "éloge"? Their definitions in the Larousse dictionary are very similar. Examples:

- Elle a reçu des compliments / louanges / éloges pour son travail bénévole.
- Il a trouvé le compliment / la louange / l'éloge très touchant(e), après tant d'années de travail.
- Les gens timides ont souvent du mal à accepter les compliments / louanges / éloges.

Comment: *Éloge* has the characteristic of being one of the few words many native French speakers are unsure about the gender.

Comment: "Compliment" est plus courant, "louanges" et "éloges" sont plus forts (peut-être simplement parce qu'ils sont moins usités). Noter que "louanges" et "éloges" sont généralement au pluriel ("compliment" est ainsi plus naturel dans le second exemple). On trouve "éloge" au singulier plutôt dans des titres de livres "éloge de X".

Answer (score 3):

1. Compliment is a polite expression of praise or admiration

   > “What a beautiful dress”
2. Louange is rather a praise

   > “This person is the most honest...”
3. Un éloge is rather used to praise someone for what he/she did and is close to louanges.
   It can also be used as funeral oration.

Comment: 1) I don't understand the difference between "a polite expression of praise or admiration" (compliment) and "praise" (louange). Every praise is polite and implies admiration.  2) Couldn't I use "compliment" and "louange" to praise someone for what he/she did? 3) Which one of these words is the most usual ?

Comment: French is about the context; you would consider « compliments » when trading lightly ; for exemple you compliment someone for his/her cloth, hair makeup or being certified

Comment: Louange is rather use in a more formal way : for example when you praise someone for what he/she accomplished during ww2. At the difference of a compliment, here you praise someone actions to someone else or to a group (and I have to say I will use this one only if the praised is dead or old enough)

Comment: In day to day life you compliment someone quite often ; in more formal occasion, you”louange” someone for what he/she did - at a wedding you compliment the groom for making the right choice and the wife for her beautiful dress and while raising a toast you “sing the louange” of the groom who had wonderful life

Comment: Hope it helps understanding the difference

Comment: It helps indeed. What did you mean exactly with "being certified"? Approved in an exam ? From your initial examples with cloth and hair, I thought "compliment" would be used for physical compliments only, but now I think it can be used in any informal context (eg compliment my friend for the university/company he entered, for his donation of gifts to poor children on Christmas or for a positive change in his personality) ?

Comment: You got it Alan! Being certified mean like compliments someone on his/her master in physics for example